# How to use jsx-control-statements in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, controls, statements

Im using jsx-control-statements in react app to add basic control statements. I've installed the same using npm and updated the .babelrc file as below

```
{
  "presets": ["react"],
  "plugins": ["jsx-control-statements"]
}
```

and I've the below jsx code

```
<IF condition={ selectedID !== null }>
 {this.renderData()}
</IF>
```

below is the function to initiate the selectID, I want to execute the renderData() only if the value not equal to null

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        selectedID: null
    }
},
```

As of now Im getting a console error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: IF is not defined" and the app is not loading. Can anyone tell me anything wrong here. Need help.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The best way to use jsx-control-statements in reactjs is NOT to use it at all. Why? because in my company we had it in our project and it only brought us unreadable, buggy and cluttered code.

Just think for a second you are encouraging moving business logic into your view component's jsx part which only should be used to output your already processed data. At first, it may look good but after a while, more and more logic will go there and it will become a problem.

So in your case what you can do is something like this:

```
{selectedID !== null && this.renderData()}
```

Comment: Boy, there is a difference between business logic and presentation logic. In the presentation layer (view), you will eventually need to use conditionals and iterators for displaying your data. This is called presentation logic and jsx-control-statements is a plugin for doing this, while following the declarative approach of JSX components.

Comment: Funny thing: you say that logic in the JSX is bad, but your example does the SAME logic, but uglier. If you are writing javascript, you better emphasise javascript syntax, if you are writing JSX, you must emphasise JSX syntax. If you don`t use jsx-control-statements, you will eventually end up using ternary operators and ugly comparisons like the one on your example in the MIDST of JSX code and this is ugly.

Comment: Last thing: the JSX AssignmentExpression, this `{ myExpression }` that you used, are meant just for simple data output, not for logic, iterations and conditionals. If you want a conditional, you have to wrap you JXS code block inside a conditional. This is the purpose of jsx-control-statements.

Comment: Where did I say JSX is bad? I love JSX. What I said is that if you have some complex logic, better extract it to Javascript function with some logic that could be easily reusable and testable, rather than creating the whole pile of JSX nesting with each other. Otherwise for simple conditionals ternary will do its job just fine. Moreover, there could be some cases when `jsx-control-statements` will work just fine, but one should be careful not to misuse it.

Comment: Just to clarify logic in the JSX is NOT bad, but it depends, if it is a complex logic it is better to be extracted from render method into Javascript function for better reusability and testability (or even extract it into another component). So, either you extract the complex logic or just JSX will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but I just came across this while googling - you want to be using `If` instead of `IF`.

I suppose not using it at all works too :|.